# Framework7 and google maps

Tags: google-maps, cordova, html-framework-7

im new to Framework7 and google maps and I try to implement a page which display a map and a search box

```
 map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div,options);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById("pac-input");

 var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
```

this is my try to make it work but i got this error message :

```
vue.common.dev.js:630 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: google is not defined"
```

can someone help or explain how to add map with search in framework7?

Comment: Can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?